# Old Device I found at a garage sale

Tags: identification

I found this instrument at a garage sale a while back.  It consists of two parts: a bent sheet metal housing with a stand near the front and rubber feet on the bottom; and an insert.

I haven’t been able to find a lot on it.  The only clue I have is the manual for HP’s vacuum tube voltmeter model 410b that I bought with it. The plug on the back matches one of the accessories used with the voltmeter mentioned in the manual.

My initial thought was that it was an oscilloscope, by the front switches being label DB, instead of dB shot that theory out the window.  I couldn’t find any units that looked like that since.

Can anyone help me out? I would be willing to answer any questions about interior items that I can.

[image: front panel of instrument]

[Link to more images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dirpB.jpg)

Update: I just dismantled the instrument.  I do think more concretely that it was a dBmV meter or a signal strength meter of some kind.  The 4 Black rectangles turned out to be variable inductors.  The three switches on the side of the front panel turned out to be toggling resistor filter for the top coaxial plug.  The plug on the back is for AC current to recharge the batteries inside, since one of the lines from the plug leads to a diode and a “Ohmite”.

I would be willing to post pictures of the individual components if any want to see

Comment: Why do you assume DB is not the same as dB?

Comment: @immibis Why would a company miss label units? It makes no sense.  Plus the batteries inside make me think otherwise also

Comment: @user3831093 But that’s kind of like saying they mislabeled “VOLT METER” because it’s in all-caps as well. It’s just the stencil they used.

Comment: @BlairFonville good point.  Even if so, what is it then? And what does D.B.M.V mean?

Comment: D.B.M.V. probably means dBmV

Comment: @user3831093 It means dB millivolts. It's another unit for dB signal strength.

Comment: @KingDuken actually that makes sense with the repeated circuit inside and the variable resistor, or capacitor

Comment: I’m guessing is some sort of power meter, maybe to peak antennas. The batteries would make it portable.

Comment: @BlairFonville you could power that with 12.5 volts.  I think.  I would have to fill dismentle it to find out where the positive end comes from.

Comment: Well, it is **not** an oscilloscope.  No screen for viewing the signal.  DB or dB has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I think it is a very old and crude selective level meter, input attenuator on the left, tuning controls on the right and meter in the middle. The monitor switch probably controls a resistive termination.

Comment: @user3831093 Well, one entire nation maked capacitors by their "M.F.D" rating or sometimes "MF", meaning megafarad when they ment uF or microfarad.

Comment: As for your perplexity about capitalization, keep in mind that making a quality silkscreen was very expensive long ago. There were no CAD systems and having stencils for different fonts, or for fonts complete with lowercase letters (let alone greek letters!) was something not every manufacturer could afford (especially for cheap or specialty equipment).

Comment: BTW, next time you post photos use a different reference for scale. A quarter of a dollar is meaningful mainly only for American people. It would be better to put a ruler somewhere in the picture. Even if it shows non-metric unit, it would be much clearer: it is much more likely that even people accustomed to metric units know that 1in=2.54cm, since 0.1in=2.54mm is the standard breadboard hole pitch.

Comment: If it was homebuilt or kit built, in the days before OpenOffice and laser printers, getting hold of lower case letters for dB and mV would be more trouble than it's worth. Looks like LETRASET, process camera, and photoresist silkscreen were involved; nothing a fancy as Tampo plates.

Comment: @JRE Absolutely it is not an oscilloscope!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I had to compare to other pictures I found, I'd say that this is an old **signal level meter**. I came to this conclusion when I saw the "D.B.M.V." on the scale. So I looked up "old dBmV meter" on Google, I saw multiple devices that shared the same characteristics. Here's something that looks like it has the same functionalities.

You can find more devices from a website called, ["Old CATV Equipment Museum"](http://theoldcatvequipmentmuseum.org/180/181/1813/index.html) so that's where I'm basing my information from.

[image]

Comment: Then why would it need a volt meter bypass?

Comment: Possibly to filter out some noise. That's a pure guess to be honest.